# Unable to produce message in Kafka when SASL_PLAINTEXT is enabled

Tags: apache-kafka

Using the command line to produce a message

kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9093 --producer.config client-properties/producer.properties --topic first-topic

I got

> org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Cannot execute transactional method because we are in an error state
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager.maybeFailWithError(TransactionManager.java:1125)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager.maybeAddPartition(TransactionManager.java:442)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:998)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:912)
> at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$.send(ConsoleProducer.scala:70)
> at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$.main(ConsoleProducer.scala:52)
> at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer.main(ConsoleProducer.scala)
> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ClusterAuthorizationException: Cluster authorization failed.
> [2022-07-29 08:15:21,556] ERROR [Producer clientId=console-producer] Aborting producer batches due to fatal error (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ClusterAuthorizationException: Cluster authorization failed.
> [2022-07-29 08:15:21,563] ERROR Error when sending message to topic first-topic with key: null, value: 4 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ClusterAuthorizationException: Cluster authorization failed.

Checking the permission

kafka-acls --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 --command-config client-properties/adminclient.properties --topic first-topic  --list

I got

> Current ACLs for resource `ResourcePattern(resourceType=TOPIC, name=first-topic, patternType=LITERAL)`:
> (principal=User:producer, host=*, operation=CREATE, permissionType=ALLOW)
> (principal=User:producer, host=*, operation=DESCRIBE, permissionType=ALLOW)
> (principal=User:consumer, host=*, operation=DESCRIBE, permissionType=ALLOW)
> (principal=User:producer, host=*, operation=WRITE, permissionType=ALLOW)
> (principal=User:consumer, host=*, operation=READ, permissionType=ALLOW)

In kafka-server.jaas, I have

```
// Server config - used to authorise
KafkaServer {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
   username="admin"
   password="admin-secret"
   user_admin="admin-secret"
   user_producer="producer-secret"
   user_consumer="consumer-secret";
};
// Client config used to connect to Kafka
KafkaClient {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
  username="admin"
  password="admin-secret";
};

// Client config user to connect to Zookeeper
Client {
  org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
  username="admin"
  password="admin-secret";
};
```

and producer.properties

```
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="producer" password="producer-secret";
```

ACL setup

```
$KAFKA_HOME/kafka-acls.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 --command-config client-properties/adminclient.properties --topic first-topic --allow-principal User:producer --producer --add
```

Comment: Double check your ACLs on the internal transactions topic, or disable transactions in the producer config (enabled by default). As error says... `Cannot execute transactional method`

Comment: HI OneCricketeer, I added the ACL command to the description. I am not sure what else needs to be included. Would you please advise?

Comment: As mentioned, there is another topic called `__transaction_state` that may have its own related ACLs and there is a flag called `--transactional-id` when adding ACLs

Comment: I am not sure it is with transactional. I was able to send a message using admin